# Does this PDE have a name?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, integrable-systems

I'm looking for any and all information that might be known about the following second-order PDE for one function $u(x,y)$:

$ u_{xy} = u_x e^u + u_y e^{-u} $

e.g., Does it have a name?  Is it known to be integrable (or not)?  Anything else interesting about it?

Comment: It might help to explain how you ran across this in your research. Why are you interested in it? It might give us a place to start looking.

Comment: Looks like some generalized version of [Liouville's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_equation).

Comment: A collaborator and I are attempting to classify second-order PDEs of a certain form that have Backlund transformations.  Most of the examples we're finding are well-known, but we didn't recognize this one.

Answer (score 3):

By changing the variables as $x=t+z$ and $y=t-z$ you get $$u_{tt} -u_{zz} =2u_t \cosh(u) +2u_z \sinh(u)$$which is a nonlinear wave equation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation#Related_equations

Comment: It's not sinh-Gordon because of the presence of the partial derivatives of u on the right-hand side.